# Highlighting individual rings in ring chart

Tags: d3.js

I am trying to draw a circular heat or ring-chart.  There are several options it seems with d3js.  The most popular appears to use the pie layout to make several [donut rings](http://jsfiddle.net/Qh9X5/154/)  Another option is to use a circular heat chart [like this one](http://prcweb.co.uk/lab/circularheat/) -

Both of these however use filling segments as their way of depicting area size.   I wanted however to use lines to depict events over time.  With each line occurring within a particular ring.

To get this effect, I've adapted this radial weather chart - http://bl.ocks.org/susielu/b6bdb82045c2aa8225f5

This is my attempt so far:
http://blockbuilder.org/jalapic/12a3a23651f40283d489

It does not have labeling, but each ring (12 total) represents an individual subject.  Each segment represents a sample of time (says months here but could be anything).  The lines are drawn within each ring that they belong to.   I have kept the same variable names as the weather example to enable comparisons between my stripped down code and the author's original code.

This is what it looks like:

[image]

My question is how might it be possible to mouseover each ring to make only that ring's contents (i.e. lines) remain visible, i.e. to hide the other rings - this would make viewing the chart easier.

Here is the code for how the rings are made up:

```
var mycircles =    [110,100, 90, 80, 70, 60,50,40,30,20,10,0] 

   origin.selectAll('circle.axis-green')
    .data(mycircles)       //original circles
    .enter()
    .append('circle')
    .attr('r', function(d) { return rScale(d)})
    .style("fill", "#fff8ee")
    .style("opacity", .05)
    .attr('class', 'axis record')
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");})       
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {d3.select(this).style("fill", "#fff8ee");
});
```

As can be seen the rings are actually overlapping circles.  Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do using the approach I'm taking, or would I have to go back to working something out with segments like in the heatchart or pie layouts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your data and code, one method would be to assign a class to each line representing it's ring position.  You can then use mouseover and mouseout events to toggle the opacity of those lines.

First, create a couple helper functions:

```
// which ring is currently highlighted
var curRing = null;
// show all rings
function unShowRing(){
  d3.selectAll(".record")
    .style("opacity", 1);
  curRing = null;
}
// only show current ring
function showRing(ringId){
  // all lines that are not in my ring, hide them
  d3.selectAll(".record:not(.ring" + ringId + ")")
        .style("opacity", 0);
  curRing = ringId;
}
```

Set up the lines a little different:

```
...
.enter().append('line')
    // assign a unique class to each ring's lines
    .attr('class', function(d) {
      return cl + " ring" + d.recLow/10;
    })
    // on mouseover only show my ring
    .on("mouseover", function(d){
      var ringId = d.recLow/10;
      showRing(ringId);
    })
    // on mouseout show all rings
    .on("mouseout", function(d){
      unShowRing();
    })
    // this will prevent lines transitioning in from being shown
    .style('opacity', function(d){
      if (!curRing){
        return 1;
      } else {
        var ringId = d.recLow/10;
        return ringId === curRing ? 1 : 0;
      }
    })
```

Finally, you'll need to handle the ring "circle" mouseovers as well in case the user mouses over lines or rings:

```
origin.selectAll('circle.axis-green')
    .data(mycircles) //original circles
    ...
    .on("mouseover", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "red");
      var ringId = d/10;
      showRing(ringId);
    })
    .on("mouseout", function(d) {
      d3.select(this).style("fill", "#fff8ee");
      unShowRing();
    });
```

Here's the [whole thing working](http://plnkr.co/edit/Hn4CE4jEK2bYAMnUSsIq?p=preview).